# SPARQL query on HM land registry site based on first part of postcode

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to find out average house price data for a postcode area using the HM Land Registry open data SPARQL query via https://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole, what the best way to do this if it's for a postcode sector (e.g. GL52)?

The 'transactions in a postcode' example code given on there shows how to search a full postcode and I have attempted to alter the code using STRSTARTS() on the VALUES ? postcode section but it's coming back with an error..

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# Returns the Price Paid data from the default graph for each transaction record having
# an address with the given postcode.
# The postcode to query is set using SPARQL 1.1's 'values' clause

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?postcode STRSTARTS({"GL52"^^xsd:string}, {"GL52"^^xsd:string})

  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode.

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.

  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
}
ORDER BY ?amount
```

Error comes back as
Encountered " "STRSTARTS" "STRSTARTS "" at line 18, column 20.
Was expecting:
"{" ...

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong I'm afraid. For this type of query, you will need a filter, like:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# Returns the Price Paid data from the default graph for each transaction record having
# an address with the given postcode.
# The postcode to query is set using SPARQL 1.1's 'values' clause

    SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category
    WHERE
    {
      ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode .
    
      ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
              lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
              lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
              lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.
      FILTER(STRSTARTS(?postcode,"GL52")) #Difference is here
    
      OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
      OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
      OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
      OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
      OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
    }
    ORDER BY ?amount
```

Now, this endpoint isn't the fastest, so this query will time out unfortunately. You can help the query performance by specifying what the county is, and the following query will produce what you're after too (and not time out):

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# Returns the Price Paid data from the default graph for each transaction record having
# an address with the given postcode.
# The postcode to query is set using SPARQL 1.1's 'values' clause

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category
WHERE
{
  #VALUES ?pc {"GL52"}

  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode ;
        lrcommon:county "GLOUCESTERSHIRE" .

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.
  FILTER(STRSTARTS(?postcode,"GL52"))

  #OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
}
ORDER BY ?amount
```

Now, if you want to look at multiple postcodes at the ame time, you might try this instead:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix sr: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/spatialrelations/>
prefix ukhpi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ukhpi/>
prefix lrppi: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/ppi/>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix lrcommon: <http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/def/common/>

# Returns the Price Paid data from the default graph for each transaction record having
# an address with the given postcode.
# The postcode to query is set using SPARQL 1.1's 'values' clause

SELECT ?paon ?saon ?street ?town ?county ?postcode ?amount ?date ?category
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?pc {"GL52" "GL51" "GL1 "}

  ?addr lrcommon:postcode ?postcode ;
        lrcommon:county "GLOUCESTERSHIRE" .

  ?transx lrppi:propertyAddress ?addr ;
          lrppi:pricePaid ?amount ;
          lrppi:transactionDate ?date ;
          lrppi:transactionCategory/skos:prefLabel ?category.
  FILTER(STRSTARTS(?postcode,?pc))

  #OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:county ?county}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:paon ?paon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:saon ?saon}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:street ?street}
  OPTIONAL {?addr lrcommon:town ?town}
}
ORDER BY ?amount
```

Which is doing the same thing, but is essentially an abbreviation.

Comment: That's fantastic thank you for explaining and giving some great examples!
It looks like it returns the full history, what would you say is best way to filter to just the last 2 years?

Comment: Try using this as your filter: 
`FILTER(STRSTARTS(?postcode,"GL52") && YEAR(?date) > 2018)`. Also don't forget to accept the answer if you think it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it using your last example where you can look up multiple postcodes but got an error back, I think I must be missing something? - 

  FILTER(STRSTARTS(?postcode,?pc)) && YEAR(?date) > 2018)

Comment: Hi I've just spotted I have one too may bracket! (Just before &&)

Comment: Could you post the whole query?

Comment: Hi @ValerioCocchi or op, wonder if either of you can help - how can I turn a SPARQL query (like the second to last filtering for G52 only) into a JSON response? The endpoint documentation isn't very easy to navigate.. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulWilson, there is a button next to 'Perform Query' where you can ask for results to be returned in JSON.
Note however that the JSON returned by SPARQL engine returns the variable 'bindings' for the query rather than house purchase transactions as objects. Let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: Hi @ValerioCocchi apprecaite the response. Sorry I wasn't explicity enough, I saw the ability to toggle JSON/table etc, but I want to query this data using Python requests lib therefore I need the full URL / endpoint. I can see the endpoint is there but I can't determine the 'URL' part and get that working.. How can I see the full URL necessary to get the JSON response? I've even poked arond 'network' tab of console with no luck. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to send the SPARQL query to http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/landregistry/query

Comment: Thanks @ValerioCocchi so possibly there's no way to actually return a JSON response in a traditional web-dev related way. Perhaps I'll reach out to HMLR and revert with what they say. Thanks again.